# Photo and Video Files Corrupted Over USB Transfer

Tags: windows-10, usb, file-corruption, transfer

I'm having an issue with transferring files over USB.  I believe it may be a problem with the controller.  The files in question are raw photo files, and video files.  I'm looking for a way to determine if it's a hardware or firmware issue.  Any searching I've done so far only brings up corrupted SD cards, and USB drives, which I've determined not to be the problem.

As far as troubleshooting, I've determined that the issue is over USB as I have tested a number of SD cards, and from both of my cameras, and have been able to view the files on other devices, such as the cameras themselves, and on my iPhone with an adapter cable.  When viewing videos from the card on my PC, they seem to be corrupted, and the copied files carry the same corruption.  I also tried transferring to different drives and continue to have the same issue, as well as tried different card readers and different USB ports.  All still experience the same problem.  I've played existing videos on my computer without any problems, so it's not an issue with playback software, or the type of files.  It definitely seems to be something wrong with how my PC reads the files over USB.

EDIT: I've found that using an intermediate device seems to solve my issues, such as connecting my camera to my PC and downloading media that way, however any attempt to directly import strait from any SD card with any adapter in any USB port still causes data to be corrupted during read and transfer.  I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling drivers for my USB 3.0 Controller, and I rolled back the drivers on my video card with no luck.

Further Tests: The issue is the same over USB 2.0 and 3.0 ports.  I don't know if it's a hardware issue, and maybe a problem with a driver as 2 of my USB 3.0 ports are connected via a PCI-E Card.  Again, this is over USB using a card reader connected to my mother board, and also a USB SD Card adapter.

I will try to include more information when available.

Thanks for the assistance.

System is Windows 10 Pro running on a Asus Z270E motherboard with a GTX 1080 graphics card.

Comment: Your description is unclear. You should exactly describe the device chain, the operating system used and the type of files because both RAW pictures and special video file formats may require additionally installed drivers.
Furthermore you should detail what you mean when talking about "corrupted SD cards".

Comment: I'm being as clear as I can be, and I never said that it was corrupted SD cards as I have tested the cards on other devices without issue, and the issue persists on my PC regardless of what card/adapter/USB port that I use, as previously stated.  Also as stated, the same file types work fine off my internal drives, and the issue only persists over USB.  I will include my PC information.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting a live distribution of linux (pick any one you like) from CD or USB and see how it behaves.

There's a difference between "container format" and "codec" so just because a ".m4v" file will play on your PC, doesn't mean the camera is encoding the same way, even though the files are also .m4v

Upgrade your media player (suggest vlc), or operating system (suggest linux)

Comment: I use VLC for just about everything.  I've checked older videos that I've taken on the same camera and transferred to my PC before having this issue, and the files on my PC work fine, while the issue over USB persists.  It's pretty standard formats.  H.264 MOV or MP4 for the video, and CR2 for the raw files. I'll give the Linux USB thing a try tho.  Thanks

Comment: If it *did* work and now it *doesn't*...there's a thing that has changed. VLC should generally have all codecs available to it so doesn't sound like codec issue. All else being the same, with the info to hand, it kinda points to a buggy windows usb driver/update. May god have mercy on you trying to roll that back.

Comment: I'm wondering if it could be a RAM issues.  I've also been having some frequent BSOD errors, and I did a memory test and windows detected some hardware issues.  I managed to get a few clean runs off of an SD card with minimal load on my RAM, but I've had mixed results when running my system normally.  Sometimes it's corrupted, others it's clean.  I might have to do some more testing, but maybe the video is getting corrupted when passing through RAM?

Comment: Frequent and/or random BSOD is just a feature of windows afaik. I wouldn't rely on windows to check your RAM either. Your BIOS/UEFI should have that built-in, or a bootable diagnostic should be available from the manufacturer. Or the venerable memtest86.